# How calculate summ Object.getItem() from List<Object> best practic?

Tags: java, collections, lambda, cycle

I have List with models

```
List<CallDetailFull> callDetails;//for example 50 items
```

It is model

```
public class CallDetailFull {
    private @Getter @Setter double dataUsage;
    private @Getter @Setter BigDecimal charge;
}
```

I need get total summ of `dataUsage` and total summ `charge`

I can make this

```
BigDecimal totalCharge = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                    int totaldataUsage = 0;
                    for(CallDetailFull item: callDetails){
                        totalCharge.add(item.getCharge());
                        totaldataUsage += item.getDataUsage();
                    }
```

But I know there is a way to solve this problem through Collections.summ() or Something like this.

Or the best solution is to add a calculation method in the model itself?

Or lambda.....

that will be the best practice and how to do it?

Comment: Define "best". Fastest? Most readable? Most compact? Beware that "best" questions are usually off-topic for SO, as they attract opinion rather than facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `BigDecimal` is an immutable class and it’s `add` method returns a new value that you *must not* drop. Further, using `+=` on an `int` variable hides the fact that you have a loss of precision due to the conversion of `double` values to `int`:

```
BigDecimal totalCharge = BigDecimal.ZERO;
double totaldataUsage = 0;
for(CallDetailFull item: callDetails){
    totalCharge = totalCharge.add(item.getCharge());
    totaldataUsage += item.getDataUsage();
}
```

After fixing that, your loop is a good solution and other solutions won’t improve that, especially as you are talking about 50 elements only.

If you really want a stream solution, you can use:

```
double totaldataUsage=callDetails.stream().mapToDouble(CallDetailFull::getDataUsage).sum();
BigDecimal totalCharge = callDetails.stream().map(CallDetailFull::getCharge)
   .reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

Comment: totalCharged = totalCharged.add(item.getCharge()); that's right?
double totalDataUsage += item.getDataUsage();

Comment: Yes, as said, the `add` method returns a new `BigDecimal` instance representing the sum of the two values. You must assign this result to the variable. The operator `+=` only works for primitive (here `double`) values.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 ways of summing in Java 8 with Streams :

```
Double sumDouble = callDetails
                   .stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(CallDetailFull::getDataUsage));

BigDecimal sumBigDecimal = callDetails
                          .stream()
                          .map(CallDetailFull::getCharge)
                          .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use you can use java 8 streams and aggregates for that, whose performance is very good:

```
list.parallelStream().mapToDouble(CallDetailFull::getDataUsage).sum();
list.stream().map(CallDetailFull::getCharge).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
```

Comment: It’s very unlikely to get a good performance with a parallel stream for adding 50 double values…